# Can't write to external drive mounted by fstab

Tags: 12.04, usb, fstab, automount, hfs+

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/12/how-to-auto-mount-external-usb-devices-in-ubuntu-12-10-quantal-quetzal/) to have Ubuntu automount an external USB drive onto the system. I added this line to `/etc/fstab`:

```
UUID=885025e1-09a5-3f29-90f6-5d07668be59b /media/Backup hfsplus rw,user,suid,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=000 0 0
```

After rebooting the machine, I navigated to `/media/Backup`. The drive showed up, and I could browse its contents, but I wasn't able to write to it (even as root). I'm on Ubuntu  Server 12.04.3.

How can I automatically mount the drive and be able to write to it, ideally as a normal user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HFS+ file systems with journaling by default can only be mounted read only on Ubuntu. You will either have to **disable journaling** on the drive or **force** the read-write mount (the latter could be dangerous). Please read [this](https://superuser.com/questions/84446/how-to-mount-a-hfs-partition-in-ubuntu-as-read-write) for detailed instructions for both solution.